# Find RowNumber in Talend

Tags: talend

How to find row number in Talend Open Studio 6.3?I want to insert rows in a order like

- Row 1 to Row 10 in File1
- Row 11 to Row 20 in File2
- Row 21 to Row30 to File3
- And then again from Row 31 to file1

How to achive that?I have generated a sequence column.now how to proceed?is it can be done using tsamplerow?
Suppose the Sourcefile is like this:-

```
EMPNO,EMPNAME,DEPTNO
10,A,1
11,B,2
12,C,3
13,D,4
14,E,1
15,F,1
16,G,2
17,H,3
18,I,4
19,J,2
20,K,3
21,L,1
22,M,2
```

Comment: So you need totally 3 files as output?

Comment: yeah.But I need to know first how to know the Rownumber count like for here RowCount=13.

Comment: That depends on the source component. Is your source data from DB or file?

Comment: Its file.What I posted is just sample of the data.

Comment: I have already done it. I used One tfileinputdelimited,then I used one tmap where I generated sequence number.den i used 2 tsamplerows where in first I used 1..4,9..12 and in 2nd tsamplerows 5..8.and it is running fine also.suppose I dont know the Rownumber and I have to generate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the current row number by defining an increment value in talend job using `Numeric.sequence("s1",1,1)`.

**Note: I have used OP's sample data and divided rows per file as 3. But in OP's scenario it is 10 rows**

Below is the sample job which I tried out,

[image]

I am generating a sequence number to know the current row number like below

[image]

After getting the current row value, I have an another variable which will be incremented for every 3 rows (in my example) like below (in OP's example, it is for every 10 rows.)

[image]

This is the expression I am doing on `SequenceRow` context variable.

`context.SequenceRow = (input_row.SequenceNumber > context.RowRangePerFile && input_row.SequenceNumber % context.RowRangePerFile == 1) ? context.SequenceRow+1 : context.SequenceRow;`

Finally I am filtering the rows in `tMap_2` based on the `SequenceRow` value, like below,

[image]

For `out1`, the filter condition is `(out2.SequenceRow > context.TotalNoOfFiles && out2.SequenceRow % context.TotalNoOfFiles == 1) || out2.SequenceRow == 1`

For `out3`, the filter condition is `(out2.SequenceRow > context.TotalNoOfFiles && out2.SequenceRow % context.TotalNoOfFiles == 2) || out2.SequenceRow == 2`

For `out4`, the filter condition is `(out2.SequenceRow > context.TotalNoOfFiles && out2.SequenceRow % context.TotalNoOfFiles == 0) || out2.SequenceRow == 3`

I have taken your sample data that you have provided in your question,

```
EMPNO,EMPNAME,DEPTNO
10,A,1
11,B,2
12,C,3
13,D,4
14,E,1
15,F,1
16,G,2
17,H,3
18,I,4
19,J,2
20,K,3
21,L,1
22,M,2
```

and I am writing every 3 rows in each file and the output I got is

[image]

Hope this may help you.

Comment: Context is very new to me.But its an awesome answer. :)

Comment: Context is just a variable which can be accessed throughout the job.